# Adding a condition to an inner join query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this inner join query:

```
select * 
from ioa_invoice_line 
INNER JOIN ioa_invoice 
    ON ioa_invoice_line.invo_id = ioa_invoice.id ;
```

Now, I want to add this condition also in the above `inner join` that is

```
where ioa_invoice_line.invo_id =234
```

Please advise how to add this condition in above query.

Comment: Just add it at the end. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

As Felix says in his comment you can add it without problems:

```
select * 
from ioa_invoice_line 
INNER JOIN ioa_invoice 
    ON ioa_invoice_line.invo_id = ioa_invoice.id
        AND ioa_invoice_line.invo_id = 234
```

Comment: No. Felix really meant to add the **WHERE** clause. The table `ioa_invoice` gets joined, but the criteria is on the first table `ioa_invoice_line`. It should hence *not* be put in the `ON` clause in order not to confuse the reader. It belongs in the `WHERE` clause (or should be changed to `invoice.id = 234` instead).

Answer (score 3):

As this is criteria on the first table, you would usually simply add this `WHERE` clause at the end of your query (before the semicolon of course).

However, you are dealing with an invoice table and its detail table here and the criteria is on the key linking the tables. So for readability, I would swap the tables and name the parent table first and join the child table. That feels more natural:

```
select * 
from ioa_invoice i
join ioa_invoice_line il on il.invo_id = i.id
where i.id = 234;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
ioa_invoice_line il
 INNER JOIN ioa_invoice i
 ON il.invo_id = i.id 
where il.invo_id = 234
```

This format use as a professional practice